# How do you give the murderer away?

Tags: technique, proofreading, mystery

'There once was a popular soap opera staged in the southern, modern capital of Imaso in Europe.
It had run for 50 years and over time produced new characters; some viewers liked them, but other viewers loathed them.
   Then there was a news broadcast breaking the news that the actors who played some characters since the mid-2000s, perished in a blazing building which was the obvious work of arsonists.'

What would the personal characteristics of the culprit be, that could be made obvious to the reader?

The scene in a particular film where a mass-murdering psychopath is looking at a photograph (of one of the families he murdered) when he's alone.
It assures the audience that this isn't a cliffhanger (film or not) it was a teqnique

Comment: 1) As written, this is very vague and I'm not sure what your question is. How is the background relevant to the question, or the title? 2) This question will have to be made more broadly applicable than just your particular story to be on-topic here. "How do you give clues to the reader about how the murderer is?" is on-topic, as long as it can be used by others.

Comment: Hi, not sure I understand what you're asking. Are you asking how to do some sort of "soft reveal", like, by showing a proof of guilt only to the audience? Or are you asking specifically how to write a reveal for the story you described in the first paragraph?

Comment: Are you asking what traits to give a character so the reader knows they're a murderer? Answers to that question could become a list of cliches to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Do it any way you want. "He's your psychopath" with apparently a posse. No better way to "give a mass murderer away" than to see how those around him and are part of his gang view him since it would appear he is their leader of some sort. A classic is of course Captain Ahab in Moby Dick. The story is not told from his point of view.